# Bigcommerce rest api

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I wrote a small application on my local wamp server to interact with bigcommerce.

I have it working well on my local machine but when I moved it to a live server the api is not responding to anything.

Here is my connection code

```
include 'bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php';

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array('store_url' => $url,'username' => $username,'api_key' => $token));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');

Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$categorycount = ceil(Bigcommerce::getCategoriesCount() / $limit);

$errors = Bigcommerce::getLastError();

print_r($errors);
```

Headache!! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine but you must include the folder: bigcommerce-api-php-master/src/Bigcommerce/Api.php
because this contains all queries for the api

Comment: @miglo not working. i dont see this in any of the bigcommerce documentation?

Comment: if work in your wampserver, then maybe you need to configure your server php.ini

Comment: @miglo i will check but I am using several other apis for other applications on this server. I am hosting on linux. I will check a different server now. Thanks.

Comment: do i need to do anything with composer when I move the application to the live server?

Comment: not necessary, i don't use composer, i only use the folder src from the master

Comment: must be blocking my ip. i will send curl requests and check returned error. thanks for your time.